# How do I get Reqid from Below Screen shot?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I get Reqid and Xdata here?

Result is coming from Odata service. I need to map Reqid and Xdata accordingly here.

[How do i get this value?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nahlr.png)

Comment: how do you expect the result? [{ Reqid: '...', Xdata: '...' }, ...] or like string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop through the array and get the reqid and Xdata for each result in the array, something like this:

```
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
       var reqID = results[i].Reqid;
       var xData = results[i].Xdata ;
    }
```